# jQuery each() results to array to php to database

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, each

Basically what I am doing is making a sort of invitation system, the user clicks on users and they go into a list,  that all works, I can get the ids of them using each() but I need to pass it through jQuery Ajax to php to send it to the database for notifications. This is basically what I have:

```
$(".group-video-create").click(function(){
    var url = $(".group-input-url").val();                                      
    var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
    var checked_url = url.match(exp,"<a href='$1'>$1</a>"); 
    if(checked_url)
    {   
        $("#group-input-names li").each(function(){ // This is the relevant code
        var user_id = $(this).attr("id");           // Here too
        });                                         // & here

        if(user_id)
        {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                //url: "",
                //data: "", //this would be an array of all of the ids, (could be 1, could be 100).
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    ///Once all invitations have been sent to the database it would then load a new div and hide the previous one. 
                    }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

if you want to see what I'm trying to accomplish just go here:

http://www.kithell.com/#/video

usr: PhpFreak@yahoo.com
pass: phpfreaklogin

It's under Group Video. (You should be automatically directed there once logged in)

Comment: jQuery is spelled "jQuery", never "Jquery".

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use [jQuery.serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to bundle up all of your form data.  Also, [jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) is a nice shortcut for doing a POST request with `jQuery.ajax`.

A rough example might look this:

```
$.post( '/my-ajax-service.php', 
        $('#MyForm').serialize(), 
        function(data, txtStatus, jqXHR) {
            //Do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possibility

http://jsfiddle.net/nickywaites/9GZ2e/

```
$(function() {

//I would use jQuery Map to build Array
//http://api.jquery.com/map/
var ids = $("#group-input-names li").map(function() {
    return $(this).attr("id");
}).get(); //Get Required to convert to regular javascript array

console.log(ids);

var invites = {}
invites.users = ids;

//Then use JSON.stringify() to pass array to server
//https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js
if (ids.length > 0) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        //url: "",
        data: JSON.stringify(invites),
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {}
    });
}

});
```